# Angular-Jasmine missing scopes in $httpbackend respond anonymous function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am writing some end-to-end tests with Protractor for and Angular app. I am currently trying to mock some http responses using angular-mock and am running into a problem with scoping that I don't understand.

```
var protractor = require('protractor');
var ngMockE2E = require('ng-mock-e2e');
var testData = require('./e2e-data.json');

describe('DataEater', function() {
    var $httpBackend = ngMockE2E.$httpBackend;
    var appUrl = browser.baseUrl + 'scheduler/data-eater/';
    var self = this;
    self.testData2 = require('./e2e-data.json');
    beforeEach(function() {
        browser.get(appUrl);
        ngMockE2E.addMockModule();
        ngMockE2E.addAsDependencyForModule('dataEater');
        $httpBackend.when('GET', '/scheduler/tasks/queue/')
            .respond(function(method, url, data) {
                console.log(testData);
                console.log(self.testData2);
                return [200, self.testData.history, {}];
            });
```

Why are neither testData or testData2 defined? How can I get this data scoped properly so that I can return it as part of the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be that you need to explicitly pass the $scope to your controller. Try something like the following code:

```
beforeEach(
        inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
            myController = _$controller_('myControllerName', {
                $scope: _$rootScope_.$new()
            });
        })
    );
```